# Symfony2/3: document manager issue with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

After installing symfony2 and mongodb by composer.json (The installations have been completed successfuly). But, when I execute the application, I get the following error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to replace alias "doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager" with "doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager".
```

This is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*"
},
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you registered the bundle? (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#register-the-annotations-and-the-bundle)

Comment: Yes, I have register well the bundle.

Comment: Are you missing the `"doctrine/mongodb-odm"` package?

Answer (score 23):

You have to add doctrine_mongodb configuration to **app/config/config.yml**

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: kickass
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your composer.json should also contain this one following line to get the actual ODM library installed. This will solve your problem

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
```